# Problema com CharIndex do SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

tudo bem?
Me encontro em um dilema quanto ao uso do Charindex do SQL Server.
Ocorre que preciso ler um campo da tabela onde encontra-se o endereço e número apenas separados por um espaço em branco.
Pensei em utilizar o comando CharIndex para procurar o espaço em branco e trazer com o comando right() o exato "pedaço" que preciso.

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
rtrim(right('RUA GENERAL MANOEL VARGAS 253', charindex(' ','RUA GENERAL MANOEL VARGAS 253')-1))
```

A idéia acima é fazer a leitura da string da direita para a esquerda, buscando com o charindex() o primeiro espaço em branco encontrado, e com este resultado, usar o right() para trazer apenas esse pedaço da string que me interessa.

Ocorre que para esta situação funciona perfeitamente:

```
  select distinct
  rtrim(right('RUA GENERAL MANOEL VARGAS 253', charindex(' ','RUA GENERAL MANOEL VARGAS 253')-1))
  from dbo.ztemp_cadclifor;
```

Resultado:

```
253      // => perfeito
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já nesta situação não funciona:

```
  select distinct
  rtrim(right('AVENIDA SAMPAIO VIANA 277', charindex(' ','AVENIDA SAMPAIO VIANA 277')-1))
  from dbo.ztemp_cadclifor;
```

Resultado:

```
ANA 277      // => aqui eu esperava o resultado = 277
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar a tentar entender a situação?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se for considerar o número do imóvel como o último elemento do endereço, então o uso da função REVERSE() facilita obter somente o número.

```
-- código #1
SELECT right (ENDERECO, (charindex (' ', reverse (ENDERECO)) -1)) as NUMERO
  from dbo.ztemp_cadclifor;
```

---

Caso necessite separar os vários elementos do endereço, sugiro leitura do artigo “[Separar em partes uma lista de valores](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/01/27/separar-conteudo-de-texto-multivalorado_string-split/)”.

Answer (score -1):

Olà, voce tentou com SUBSTRING_INDEX?

```
SELECT distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX('AVENIDA SAMPAIO VIANA 277',' ',-1)
FROM
  dbo.ztemp_cadclifor;
```